# Jmeter randomize thoughput controler

Tags: jmeter

I need to simulate the following:

- 10 Throughput controller will run only once per player, Total executions, and is executing HTTP request every 5 minutes
- 1 Throughput controller will run 80 runs,Total executions
- 2 Throughput controller will run 20 runs,Total executions

How is to manage this.

I have tried with Random order controller

- 10X throughput controller Total execution 1  loop every 5 minutes
- throughput controller Total execution 80
- throughput controller Total execution 20

and i did not get result as i want.

Minimal running  threads is 12. Each tread for one controller.

Please does any one have idea how to solve this issue?

Comment: I have solved my issue:                                             1.)Loop                                                             1.1)Random controler                                                    1.1.1)Throughput controler  1                                                                   1.1.2)Throughput controler  90                                                                  1.1.3)Throughput controler  10

Comment: Antoher issiue how it was solved I have created a Loop controler and add if cluseses with condition "${__threadNum()}==1" and add Throughtput controler (only once to execute), under loop ad new if cluseses with condition "${__threadNum()}==2" and add Throughtput controler(only once to execute) and so on... At last add random controler with thzoughput contorlers